# Question >> print "True" or "False" if the string contains two or more characters

Tags: java, string

I have to make a method named 'contains' that accepts a string and a character as parameters and returns true if that character occurs two or more times in the string.

> example: Input  contains("Apple", 'p') should return "True"

```
private boolean contains(String a,char b) { 

    if(a.contains(b)) {
        print("true");
    }
    else {
        print("");
    }
    //boolean c = a.contains('l');
    return false;
    }
```

I know this code is wrong ... I want to know what I have to do and what I have to fix .
I would appreciate your advice 
Thank you.

Comment: `a.chars().filter(c -> c == b).count() >= 2`

Comment: The best way would be to iterate and count. See the @Scary Wombat's answer

Comment: Whenever the phrase "... or more times ..."  is part of the problem statement, a **loop** should immediately go on your list of possible solutions.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

```
  public class Demo {

    public static boolean contains(String str,char c){
        //todo:check str for NullPointExecption
        int flag=0;
        for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++){
            if(c==str.charAt(i)){
                flag++; //if str contains char c,flag=flag+1
            }
            if(flag>=2){
                return true; //if flag>=2,return true
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(contains("appple", 'p'));//result is true
    }
}
```

Comment: so @K.Fred you choose this answer because it did all the work for you, offered no explanation and use exactly the same logic as my answer 13 minutes later.

Comment: I'd request that those who are downvoting this answer explain their reasoning as the OP is a new contributor. @OP My guess would be because this is a code-only answer. You should explain why you did what you did and how it works; especially since the questioner indicates they are new to Java.

Comment: @Scary Wombat Are you angry with not be chosen by me? This is the way how I study :(  and I know yours and Humy's code had same logic  I was just checking what your code was meant. In that instant Humy gave the complete solution with comment , that's the reason why I chose him.

Comment: @Scary Wombat I know  you are thinking of me as a Student who is just Ask for the answer. But I'm not .

Comment: @Slaw sorry to my mistake,i join stackoverflow today with my pool Englist, i edited this answer and comment with the help of a translator, as you can see, I have a lot of grammatical mistakes. And I think my answer is easy to understand. No complex API and syntax are used . Question: Is OP means who Answered the question?

Comment: @iLoveHumyForever Depends on the context. In this context, "OP" means "Original Poster" and I'm referring to you.

Comment: @Slaw Thanks for you , I even thought that OP means One Piece.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to do this but the simplest would just be to loop through the String looking for the char, if count reaches two then return true.

For this consider using

```
for (char c : input) {

  if (c == myChar) count++;
  if (count >= 2) return true;
}
return false;
```

Another way would be to use String.replace and replace the wanted char with `""`
then compare the size of the before and after String

Comment: I think we should use *if (count == 2) return true;* because  count > 2  will not ececute if we return when count==2

Comment: I would say `> 1` is the best ;)

Comment: I'm not saying you're wrong but if you're returning at count==2 then do we need `>=`?

Comment: @suvojit_007 It is a safety mechanism that I was taught 30 years ago, not relevant in this case, but `>= 2` catches 2 or 3 or 4 etc whereas `== 2` only catches `2`

Comment: @ColdIV I disagree as `2` is part of specification. In years to come when the OP is searching his code for where it being returned at `2` he will find it easier.  Of course his should be using some kind of CONSTANT, but that is another story for another day.

Comment: @ScaryWombat You are absolutely correct. We don't need to check for `>2` in this case.

Comment: @ScaryWombat It wasn't meant to be taken to serious. Of course when it comes to readability, which is very important, `count >= 2` is the best solution. I just wanted to point out that there are many ways you could do this, and there really isn't "the" solution.

Comment: @ColdIV I did think think you were being serious, but I was free to ramble, so that is what I did - have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

`countMatches(a,b)` returns the count of b in `String` a. and it is from `org.apache.commons.lang3`

```
private boolean contains(String a,char b) { 
    return StringUtils.countMatches(a, b)>=2 ;
}
```

or in simple java you can use

```
private boolean contains(String a,char b) { 
    return (a.length() - a.replaceAll(String.valueOf(b),"").length())>=2 ;
}
```

Comment: `replace` would be better

Comment: yes. but its perfectly works fine. I don't know why people put -2. Atleast they have to tell me why they are putting -1. There in no error in it.

Comment: I think so,, why did they put - .. and I checked your codes work on eclipse but it was hard to understand to me .. ^^; ; cause I'm new in Java . Anyway thank you for your comment :D

Answer (score 0):

Your method may return a boolean based on the size difference between the original string, and the string without the given character :

```
return (a.length() - (a.replace(b, '')).length()) >= 2 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

In theoretical terms:

First: you need to iterate over the input string characters using a for loop and then in each iteration compare the current character in the string with the other character argument which is given as method argument. If they match, then you can increase a counter (a variable). Then compare if the counter value is 2 and return true immediately it is so. At the method end you can return false just like you have done already.

Second : you are printing true , not returning true. Should use *return true;* when the value of variable becomes 2

Answer (score 0):

This is one of simple ways to do this. Here the string is put into char array. This way it is easier to examine the elements of the char array and find out same characters.

```
private boolean contains(String a, char b) {

    char[] c_array = a.toCharArray();
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < c_array.length; i++) {
        if (b == c_array[i]) {
            count++;
            continue;
        } else {
            continue;
        }
    }
    if (count >= 2) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Few small nitpicks. (1) The `continue`s are unnecessary (and I'd argue harms readability). (2) You loop over the entire `String` no matter what, but the method's contract only requires the character to show up twice. In other words, you should break out of the loop as soon as `count == 2`. (3) I'd prefer using `return count >= 2` over the if-else solution.

Comment: Yes, that is true. Thanks for that.